# Bootstrap 3 Nav Tabs on Top and Bottom of Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a site in Bootstrap 3 and have figured out that you can indeed place both a top nav-tab and bottom nav-tab section on the same page. These two separate tab menus will trigger the same tab content areas to show/hide.

Doing this works just fine with one problem.  The tabs work independently of one another. I need the top and bottom tabs to show the same active tab. Right now if you click tab 4 on the top tab menu, it will take you to tab 4 but the bottom menu still shows the active tab as tab 1.

So, can Javascript/Jquery handle this issue? Just need them to act as the same menu.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-below">
```

Should match top nav tabs.

http://jsfiddle.net/UT6ex/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of listening to raw clicks, listen to the events triggered by the [Bootstrap Tab class](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs): `show.bs.tab` and `shown.bs.tab`. That will ensure future versions of Bootstrap markup won't break your setup.

This code finds `<li>` elements after a `shown` event to add and remove classes ([working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssorallen/UT6ex/5/)):

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab',
  function(event) {
    var $relatedTarget, $target;

    if (event.relatedTarget != null) {
      $relatedTarget = $(event.relatedTarget);
      $('a[data-toggle="' +
        $relatedTarget.attr('data-toggle') +
        '"][href="' +
        $relatedTarget.attr('href') +
        '"]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (event.target != null) {
      $target = $(event.target);
      $('a[data-toggle="' +
        $target.attr('data-toggle') +
        '"][href="' +
        $target.attr('href') +
        '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: ssorallen... you are a life saver!!! Your code worked perfectly and makes total sense. Thank you so much!  Great work.

Answer (score 0):

Sth like this is ok i suppose:

```
$('.nav-tabs').find('li').on('click', function(){
    var location = $(this).find('a').attr('href'),
    children = $('.nav-tabs').find('li'),
    links = children.find('a');
    links.each(function() {
        var mi        = $(this),
            miHrefs   = mi.attr("href"),
            miParents = mi.closest('li');

        miParents.removeClass('active');
        if(miHrefs == location) 
        {            
            miParents.addClass("active");
        }
    });  
})
```

Ok this works fine. Have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/UT6ex/4/.

Comment: This code kind of works.  It removes the active class altogether from the non-active tab. Which may work because it's at least not mis-leading.  I'd still like to see you guys mess around with the fiddle.  Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: marios... the tabs act the way they should in your fiddle, but notice the content within them does not change.  The content should change dynamically with tab selection. Other than that, it's exactly what I need! Thanks again.